# Pyspark RAM leakage

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My spark codes recently causes ram leakage. For instance, before running any script, when I run top, I can see 251 GB total memory and 230 GB free + used memory.

When I run my spark job through `spark-submit`, regardless of whether the job is completed or not (ending with exception) the free + used memory is much lower than the start. This is one sample of my code:

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    def read_df(spark, jdbc_url, table_name, jdbc_properties ):
        df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, properties=jdbc_properties)
        return df
    
    
    def write_df(result, table_name, jdbc_properties):
        result = result.repartition(50)
        result.write.format('jdbc').options(
            url=jdbc_properties['jdbc_url'],
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver",
            user=jdbc_properties["user"],
            password=jdbc_properties["password"],
            dbtable=table_name,
            mode="overwrite"
        ).save()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
            .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "postgresql-42.5.2.jar").config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","postgresql-42.5.2.jar") \
            .config("spark.local.dir", "/shared/hm31") \
            .config("spark.master", "local[*]") \
            .getOrCreate()
    
    
    
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    
        parquet_path = '/shared/hossein_hm31/embeddings_parquets'
    
        try:
    
            unique_nodes = read_df(spark, jdbc_url, 'hm31.unique_nodes_cert', jdbc_properties)
            df = spark.read.parquet(parquet_path)
    
    
            unique_nodes.createOrReplaceTempView("unique_nodes")
            df.createOrReplaceTempView("all_embeddings")
    
            sql_query = """
                select u.node_id, a.embedding from unique_nodes u inner join all_embeddings a on u.pmid = a.pmid
            """
            result =  spark.sql(sql_query)
    
      
    
            print("num", result.count())
            result.repartition(10).write.parquet('/shared/parquets_embeddings/')
    
            write_df(result, 'hm31.uncleaned_embeddings_cert', jdbc_properties)
    
    
    
    
            spark.catalog.clearCache()
            unique_nodes.unpersist()
            df.unpersist()
            result.unpersist()
    
            spark.stop()
            exit(0)
    
    
    
    
        except:
            print('Error')
            spark.catalog.clearCache()
            unique_nodes.unpersist()
            df.unpersist()
            spark.stop()
            exit(0)
    
    
        print('Error')
        spark.catalog.clearCache()
        unique_nodes.unpersist()
        df.unpersist()
        spark.stop()
        exit(0)
```

Where I tried to remove cached data frames. This RAM leakage would need a server restart, which is uncomfortable.

This is the command I run:

```bash
spark-submit --master local[50] --driver-class-path ./postgresql-42.5.2.jar --jars ./postgresql-42.5.2.jar --driver-memory 200g --conf "spark.local.dir=./logs" calculate_similarities.py
```

And this is the top output, that you can see free + used memory is much less than the total, and used to be around 230 before I ran my spark job. The jobs are sorted by memory usage, and you can see there is no memory-intensive job running after the spark ended with an exception.

I shall add that the machine does not have Pyspark itself. It has Java  11, and I just run Pyspark by importing its package.

[image]

Thanks

P.S: The `unique_nodes` is around 0.5 GB on Postgres. The `df = spark. read.parquet(parquet_path)` reads 38 parquet files, each around 3 GB. After joining, the `result` is around 8 GB.

Comment: Remove from `clearCache() unpersist() stop()` that have no use here, and try to remove the `repartition(50)` and `repartition(10)`. If not enough, try removing the `unique_nodes.createOrReplaceTempView("unique_nodes")` and `df.createOrReplaceTempView("all_embeddings")` that aren't required to execute your code.

Comment: What are your settings, btw? For a computer having 64 MB I choose: `master.uri=local[12], spark.driver.memory=2g, spark.executor.memory=2g, spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g`. Your `--driver-memory 200g` looks strong to me. Each of your `--master local[50]` should have a bit of your memory. Not a big block reserved for the driver.

Comment: Last, when you set: `--master local[50]` do you really have so much CPUs on your standalone computer? I now that you can rise that number over your CPU number to reach a virtual CPU number (for me, I have 16 cores →32 vCPU) or even go over and increase again multithreading to rise 50, like you're doing, but I'm not found of. Me, I left `local[12]` so I'm sure it will use only 12 of the 16 cores. I wonder if you are not asking your computer too much.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Thank you for your answer. I'll change my code and reply. The machine I use (based on Top_ has around 230 GB of free RAM and 256 CPUs. Actually, it is only one server, not a cluster of nodes. So I thought I would have to give a large driver memory. I also updated my question to reflect the data frame size.

Comment: If you have 230 GB and 50 CPU used of your 256 for that job, I recommend you to reduce and try `spark.driver.memory=4g, spark.executor.memory=4g, spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g` and if your job fails, grow the driver to 8g. If it happens that is not working, it means that Spark is unable to send data step by step: it would be strange and hard. And then I would look for a problem or partitioning. Your data aren't partitioned by a criteria. It could help Spark, if they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "RAM leakage" here. You're mis-interpreting what `top` is displaying:

- `total` is the total amount of memory (no surprises)
- `free` is the amount of memory that is unused for any purpose
- `used` is what the kernel currently has allocated, e.g. due to requests from applications
- the sum of `free`+ `used` is *not* `total`, because there is also `buff/cache`. This is the amount of memory currently used for "secondary" purposes, especially caching data that is on disk for which the kernel knows it already has an exact copy in memory; as long as there is no memory-pressure by `used`, the kernel will try to keep it's `buff/cache`.
- `avail` is what is readily available to be used by applications, approximately the sum of `free` + `buff/cache`

Your `top` screenshot shows large amount of memory allocated to `buff/cache`, which is probably data that was ready previously and which the kernel keeps around in case it is needed later; there is no "leakage" here, because the kernel will evict these cached memory page if the need by applications arrives. Also notice that the `avail` number is still around 234gb, which is almost exactly what you expected from `free` + `used` - but didn't take into account `buff/cache`.

Comment: Does it mean I should ignore that number and just submit my Spark/other jobs as if those were free RAM?

Comment: @m0ss, for some definition of "ignore", yes. What you are primarily concerned with is the `avail Mem` while everything is executing. If this number goes towards zero, the kernel is forced to swap out stuff onto disk, which is obviously horribly slow. However, there might be benefits to a larger pool of `avail` if `buff/cache` is used frequently: If the applications indulge memory and thereby force cached pages out of the cache, overall performance might suffer. But in general: There is no "RAM leakage" here, at least not from what you reported. It's fine.